# OWASP ESAPI and SLF4J/Logback setup

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, esapi

I currently have a program that uses SLF4J/LoggerFactory for capturing logs and the configuration is done through logback.xml. My logs were working as expected. I was recently instructed by the Security team at my job to update a class which uses ESAPI. I updated the class and added `ESAPI.properties` and `validation.properties` to `src/main/resources/esapi`. In `ESAPI.properties`, I updated ESAPI.Logger to `ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory`. Based on my research online and through SO, I assumed I would be able to us my logs (which is initialized as `protected final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);` and used as `log.info("Example")`) as normal (outputs the logs to a file on a server) but the logs just output to the CL when the java program is run.

Comment: I would start here:  https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Using-ESAPI-with-SLF4J

And there is some important log config messaging here:  https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.1.0-release-notes.txt  That might help.  

We default to the programmer for log config:  ESAPI just needs to know what framework to use and assumes you've configured it accordingly.  I suspect a RACE between when ESAPI instantiates a logger and when you've already loaded it in your application.  ESAPI needs to be first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If I have all the configuration I need in my ```logback.xml``` file, do I need to declare anything in ```ESAPI.properties``` other than ```ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory```.  I am getting command line logs that the ```ESAPI.properties``` and ```validation.properties```  are Successfully Loaded before my program runs. Would that rule out a RACE issue? If not, how would I resolve that? Thanks!

Comment: Jeremiah actually answers your question:  you need to change your coding references to ESAPI as opposed to slf4j.  My guess here is that eliminates the RACE condition because if all log calls are ESAPI, then slf4j can't instantiate except through ESAPI.  

There wouldn't be a better solution:  ESAPI was coded as singletons unfortunately so you will be on your own if you want to figure out a way to run both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue after reading the [README.md](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy) for the current release which references the [2.2.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/main/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.3.0-release-notes.txt) if you are using the slf4j libraries. I needed to exclude the slf4j-simple which is pulled in because it is a dependency of AntiSamy 1.6.2.

Answer (score 3):

The configuration for the LogFactory indicates which Logging Framework instance org.owasp.esapi.Logger should delegate to.

From your question, it appears you are expecting a log event to follow the flow of:

MyCode -> SLF4J -> ESAPI -> Console.

In actuality, the way it's implemented is:
MyCode -> ESAPI_LOGGER -> SLF4J -> Console

The ESAPI Logger is not an implementation of the SLF4J logging contract. It will only delegate to the logger instance configured in esapi.properties.  All of the references in code will need to be updated to

```
Logger esapiLogger = ESAPI.getLogger(myLogger_byClass_or_byName)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are also these relevant properties in the **ESAPI.properties** file that you may wish to tweak:

```
# ESAPI Logging
# Set the application name if these logs are combined with other applications
Logger.ApplicationName=ExampleApplication
# If you use an HTML log viewer that does not properly HTML escape log data, you can set LogEncodingRequired to true
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the application name. This might be clutter in some single-server/single-app environments.
Logger.LogApplicationName=true
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the server IP and port. This might be clutter in some single-server environments.
Logger.LogServerIP=true
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the user info.
Logger.UserInfo=true
# Determines whether ESAPI should log the session id and client IP.
Logger.ClientInfo=true
```